# Visual Studio Code no autocompleta mi codigo c++

Tags: c++, vscode

estoy usando visual studio code, pero el problema es que no me sugiere autocompletado en mi codigo, por ejemplo ni siquiera muestra las librerias que hay disponibles para importar, en las clases que creo no me sugiere la existencia de los atributos de la clase o cuando declaro un vector ni siquiera sugiere autocompletar la palabra, el numero de cosas que autocompleta es muy limitado, ya probé instalando todas las extensiones de c++ y verificando que este activo el intellissense pero nada, alguien podria decirme que falla?, por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo estas extensiones de c++ instaladas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probablemente alguna de las extensiones este haciendo conflicto sobre las otras, prueba deshabilitando primero las que no son de Microsoft.